# Hide NSDocument subclass from Launch Services

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist

I have a pair of apps that are basically twins - one is a client and the other a server. They share much of the same code and both use the same NSDocument subclass to implement a document format that they share. The client app has a user interface and allows users to visually work with the documents, but the server app does not (though it does run as a regular app, not as a daemon), it is designed to run invisibly.

The problem is that the server app gets triggered when a document is dropped on it's icon. The server app is also triggered if it is running and the client app is not running, and the user double clicks on a document. In that case what I want to happen is for Launch Services to launch the client app and open the document, instead, it tries to open the document using the server app. I have customized the NSApplicationDelegate `application:openFile:` method so that the server app refuses to actually open the document in that situation, but what I want is for NSApplicationDelegate to not invoke it with document open events. It's confusing for the user because they expect double clicking the document to open the client app, whether the server app is running or not.

Apple's Core Foundation Keys documentation seems to indicate that the way to do this is using the *LSHandlerRank* property.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1

For the client app, I have set this to "Owner".

```
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Owner</string>
```

For the server app, I set it to "None".

```
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>None</string>
```

Unfortunately, this had no effect. I could still drop documents on the server app icon, or double click on a document to bring the server app forward if the client app isn't running.

Another property that I thought might be promising is *CFBundleTypeRole*. The plist for the client app sets this to "Editor".

```
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Editor</string>
```

The documentation for this property is really sparse, but it does say that "None" is an option. So I tried that in the server app plist, and then I could no longer open my NSDocument files programmatically. On the other hand, dropping the document on the server app icon *still* caused the icon to light up, so Launch Services apparently still thinks that the server app can handle this type of file.

To summarize, what I need is some change to the plist so that I can still programmatically work with files associated with my NSDocument subclass, but I don't want Launch Services to know that my (server) app can work with these documents. Is this possible?

---- Follow up to Peter Hosey's answer ----

Thanks for this answer. I was not aware of the lsregister shell command and it looks very handy. A dump produces 46 megabytes of data on my machine!

However, I'm pretty sure this is not a caching issue. Though my computer has multiple copies of the server app, this issue was discovered by a customer. He has only one copy of the app, and he's only had it a short time. I haven't changed the plist contents in over a year, so there would be nothing to cache on his system.

You suggest not using Launch Services, but I didn't make myself clear, I am not taking advantage of it, and do not want Launch Services to open my documents (at least not with the server version of my app). In fact, I have successfully modified the app so that if Launch Services does request the server app to open a document, it ignores this request. Opening of documents is being done thru an internal TCP/IP server, which uses `openDocumenWithContentsOfURL`, like this:

```
[sharedDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:databaseURL display:openWindows error:&err];
```

The `openDocumenWithContentsOfURL` method seems to require that the plist be set up for the document type. My problem is, this also tells Finder that this application can handle this type of document, which I don't want. So I'm looking for some way that I can use NSDocument within the application, but not expose that to the Finder (so I think not expose this to Launch Services). Perhaps that isn't possible.

Is there some method for opening a document without a URL, so that it doesn't matter what the extension is or how the plist is set up? I don't see any such documented method in the NSDocumentController class. It looks to me, and testing seems to confirm, that the NSDocument class relies on the plist to link file extensions to NSDocument subclasses.

If there is a way to change the plist to do this, then I'm definitely going to need to use lsregister to clear the cache's to test this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohhh, so you're not using Launch Services (or Apple Events) to send the “document” to the server, but the server handles requests (received by other means) by “opening” the “document” using NSDocumentController. And what you're finding is that NSDocumentController requires the document types in the Info.plist in order to know which NSDocument subclass to use.

This is something you can override in your NSDocumentController subclass:

- `-typeForContentsOfURL:error:`: Given a URL, return a string indicating what type of document that URL refers to. Default behavior does this by finding a type that has the URL's `pathExtension` among its tags. Depending on how strict you want to be, you could do similar checks and only return a type name if it's a document plausibly sent in by your client, or you could be lazy and just return a constant string (if your server only handles one type of “document”).
- `-documentClassForType:`: Given a document type name, return an NSDocument subclass to instantiate to manage a document of that type. As long as you only handle one type and therefore have only one NSDocument subclass, you might return your NSDocument subclass unconditionally; if you have multiple such subclasses or want to plan for a future in which you might, compare the type name to each known type name and return the appropriate subclass.
- `-displayNameForType:`: Given a document type name, return a localized string containing a user-presentable name of that type (e.g., “web page” in English, instead of “public.html”). May not be needed in your case.
- `-documentClassNames`: Returns an array of names of NSDocument subclasses that might be instantiated to manage documents the application can handle. May not be necessary for your purposes, but the default implementation consults your Info.plist.
- `-defaultType`: The name of the document type to use for new documents (as in the `newDocument:` action). May not be relevant if you aren't creating new documents from the server, but the default implementation consults your Info.plist (it returns the first type for which you've declared yourself an Editor).

With these methods overridden in your NSDocumentController subclass, your document controller will no longer consult Info.plist, and you can remove the Info.plist information about document types that you don't want LS to know about.

If you're not already using an NSDocumentController subclass, you'll need to make one, and call `[MyDocumentController sharedDocumentController]` early in your program (you might even have to do it in `main` to do it before nibs load; it's been awhile since I've looked at when and where the document controller gets instantiated). Sending that message to your subclass will ensure the document controller gets created from that subclass, and thereby has the behavior you implemented in that subclass.

Comment: Overriding -typeForContentsOfURL: and -documentClassForType: to return hard coded values (I duplicated Apple's logic, but not referencing the plist) then removing the CFBundleDocumentTypes entries from the plist did the trick. I also did have to use lsregister to clear the LS cache after making those changes, as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the challenges in working with LS is cache invalidation (famously one of the two hardest problems in computer science, along with naming things and off-by-one errors). LS wants to cache everything for performance reasons, so when you change something, it then becomes important to make sure the old info gets purged from LS's database.

The first thing to check is how many copies of the server app you have. If you ever copied it out of the build products folder, that old copy might be the one that LS is trying to handle the document with.

The second thing to check is what copies of the server app LS thinks you have, and what it thinks they can handle.

The way to do both of these is with `lsregister -dump`. lsregister is squirrelled away at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister, and its dump will give you a wealth of information about what types (UTIs) are registered, what app bundles are registered (including different versions at different locations with different capabilities), services, etc.

`lsregister -help` will tell you about its other options, some of which may help in driving out the outdated/unhelpful records from LS's database.

I'd probably avoid using LS for this. Maybe import the type in the server app's Info.plist, but don't list it as a document type, and don't use LS from the client to open the document with the server app.

Instead, make your own Open Documents event with NSAppleEventDescriptor, then send it to the server app using `AESendMessage`. The event class is `kCoreEventClass`, and the event ID is `kAEOpenDocuments`. The target descriptor should be an NSAppleEventDescriptor of type `typeApplicationBundleID`, containing the server app's bundle ID as a string.

Set the event's `keyDirectObject` keyword parameter to a list descriptor of at least one `typeFileURL` descriptor containing the URL of a document to open (also represented as a string).